# Nomachine: The server was unable to make the local display available or access to the local display is disabled

Tags: server, nomachine

After my server has run out of RAM, unstable nomachine remote desktop tool has disconnected and now, after reboot of the server, it doesn't want to connect saying:

> The server was unable to make the local display available or access to
> the local display is disabled.

I tried reinstalling server-side nomachine's DEB file with purging. Tried reinstalling MATE desktop, I still get this message and I don't know what to do. How to make it work again?

Tried to run **/usr/NX/bin/nxserver --restart** it also doesn't help.

Also tried restarting nxserver service, I've found some strange errors in journalctl:

```
Feb 17 01:42:44 37-61-214-198 nxexec[3532]: (mount.c:72): Messages from underlying mount program:
Feb 17 01:42:44 37-61-214-198 nxexec[3532]: (mount.c:76): mount error: could not resolve address for SERVEUR: Unknown error
Feb 17 01:42:44 37-61-214-198 nxexec[3532]: (pam_mount.c:522): mount of public failed
Feb 17 01:42:44 37-61-214-198 nxexec[3532]: (mount.c:72): Messages from underlying mount program:
Feb 17 01:42:44 37-61-214-198 nxexec[3532]: (mount.c:76): mount error: could not resolve address for SERVEUR: Unknown error
Feb 17 01:42:44 37-61-214-198 nxexec[3532]: (pam_mount.c:522): mount of commun failed
Feb 17 01:42:54 37-61-214-198 nxexec[6004]: pam_unix(nx:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=129)
Feb 17 01:43:11 37-61-214-198 systemd[1]: nxserver.service: Succeeded.
Feb 17 01:43:11 37-61-214-198 systemd[1]: Stopped NoMachine Server daemon.
Feb 17 01:43:12 37-61-214-198 systemd[1]: Started NoMachine Server daemon.
Feb 17 01:43:13 37-61-214-198 nxexec[6212]: pam_unix(nx:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=129)
Feb 17 01:44:16 37-61-214-198 nxexec[6633]: pam_ldap(nx:account): error reading from nslcd: Connection reset by peer
Feb 17 01:46:59 37-61-214-198 systemd[1]: Stopping NoMachine Server daemon...
Feb 17 01:46:59 37-61-214-198 nxexec[6212]: (mount.c:72): Messages from underlying mount program:
Feb 17 01:46:59 37-61-214-198 nxexec[6212]: (mount.c:76): mount error: could not resolve address for SERVEUR: Unknown error
Feb 17 01:46:59 37-61-214-198 nxexec[6212]: (pam_mount.c:522): mount of gdm failed
Feb 17 01:46:59 37-61-214-198 nxexec[6212]: (mount.c:72): Messages from underlying mount program:
Feb 17 01:46:59 37-61-214-198 nxexec[6212]: (mount.c:76): mount error: could not resolve address for SERVEUR: Unknown error
Feb 17 01:46:59 37-61-214-198 nxexec[6212]: (pam_mount.c:522): mount of public failed
Feb 17 01:46:59 37-61-214-198 nxexec[6212]: (mount.c:72): Messages from underlying mount program:
Feb 17 01:46:59 37-61-214-198 nxexec[6212]: (mount.c:76): mount error: could not resolve address for SERVEUR: Unknown error
Feb 17 01:46:59 37-61-214-198 nxexec[6212]: (pam_mount.c:522): mount of commun failed
Feb 17 01:47:09 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7379]: pam_unix(nx:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=129)
Feb 17 01:47:11 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7379]: (mount.c:72): Messages from underlying mount program:
Feb 17 01:47:11 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7379]: (mount.c:76): mount error: could not resolve address for SERVEUR: Unknown error
Feb 17 01:47:11 37-61-214-198 systemd[1]: nxserver.service: Succeeded.
Feb 17 01:47:11 37-61-214-198 systemd[1]: Stopped NoMachine Server daemon.
Feb 17 01:47:11 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7379]: (pam_mount.c:522): mount of gdm failed
Feb 17 01:47:11 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7379]: (mount.c:72): Messages from underlying mount program:
Feb 17 01:47:11 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7379]: (mount.c:76): mount error: could not resolve address for SERVEUR: Unknown error
Feb 17 01:47:11 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7379]: (pam_mount.c:522): mount of public failed
Feb 17 01:47:11 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7379]: (mount.c:72): Messages from underlying mount program:
Feb 17 01:47:11 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7379]: (mount.c:76): mount error: could not resolve address for SERVEUR: Unknown error
Feb 17 01:47:11 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7379]: (pam_mount.c:522): mount of commun failed
Feb 17 01:47:12 37-61-214-198 systemd[1]: Started NoMachine Server daemon.
Feb 17 01:47:12 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7552]: pam_unix(nx:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=129)
Feb 17 01:47:26 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7632]: pam_ldap(nx:account): error reading from nslcd: Connection reset by peer
Feb 17 01:49:19 37-61-214-198 systemd[1]: Stopping NoMachine Server daemon...
Feb 17 01:49:19 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7552]: (mount.c:72): Messages from underlying mount program:
Feb 17 01:49:19 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7552]: (mount.c:76): mount error: could not resolve address for SERVEUR: Unknown error
Feb 17 01:49:19 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7552]: (pam_mount.c:522): mount of gdm failed
Feb 17 01:49:19 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7552]: (mount.c:72): Messages from underlying mount program:
Feb 17 01:49:19 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7552]: (mount.c:76): mount error: could not resolve address for SERVEUR: Unknown error
Feb 17 01:49:19 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7552]: (pam_mount.c:522): mount of public failed
Feb 17 01:49:19 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7552]: (mount.c:72): Messages from underlying mount program:
Feb 17 01:49:19 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7552]: (mount.c:76): mount error: could not resolve address for SERVEUR: Unknown error
Feb 17 01:49:19 37-61-214-198 nxexec[7552]: (pam_mount.c:522): mount of commun failed
Feb 17 01:49:29 37-61-214-198 nxexec[8168]: pam_unix(nx:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=129)
Feb 17 01:49:46 37-61-214-198 systemd[1]: nxserver.service: Succeeded.
Feb 17 01:49:46 37-61-214-198 systemd[1]: Stopped NoMachine Server daemon.
Feb 17 01:49:46 37-61-214-198 systemd[1]: Started NoMachine Server daemon.
Feb 17 01:49:47 37-61-214-198 nxexec[8347]: pam_unix(nx:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=129)
Feb 17 01:50:03 37-61-214-198 nxexec[8445]: pam_ldap(nx:account): error reading from nslcd: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: How do you know it has run out of ram?

Comment: I was running memory intensive app.

Comment: That is really not an answer.